# Volley StringRequest handled by RequestQueue crashes without error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

This is the code that is crashing:

```
val url = "https://chotawhatsapp.firebaseio.com/users.json"
val res = object : Response.Listener<String> {         
    //Toast.makeText(this@Main2Activity,"show",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    @Override
    override fun onResponse(s: String) {          
        Toast.makeText(this@Main2Activity,"show",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        doOnSuccess(s)
        //the function OnResponse is shown never used in the program while toast is properly executable
    }
}

val eros = object :Response.ErrorListener {
@Override
override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError: VolleyError) {
        Toast.makeText(this@Main2Activity,"volley error - $volleyError",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

//  request = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,)
val request = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, res,eros)

val rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@Main2Activity)
rQueue.add(request)
```

There is nothing in logcat for the crash.

The toast messages in the code are not shown.

Comment: Hi Pulkit. I added your code to a new Kotlin project. It worked fine with only minor changes. I've included additional information with regards to my setup. If you are still having problems let me know and I can help you investigate. But please let me know the last line you are able to break on before it crashes. Also try get logcat working 1. Ensure the right device is selected in the top left hand side 2. Press green restart widget 3. Restart Android Studio. Also make sure verbose is on and there is nothing in the logcat search widget. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for me. Only minor differences:

```
fun f() {
    val url = "https://www.google.co.uk/"
    val res = object :Response.Listener<String>{
        override fun onResponse(response: String?) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"no err: $response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    val eros = object :Response.ErrorListener {
        @Override
        override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError: VolleyError){
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"volley error - $volleyError", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    //  request = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,)
    val request = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, res,eros)

    val rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)
    rQueue.add(request)
}
```

Gradle:

```
 implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Project creation procedure:

```
 File -> New Project -> [Tick box: Include Kotlin Support]
```

I mention this procedure because I've often been less than lucky when converting existing Java apps to Kotlin.

I could not remember if Volley posted its results back to the main thread or a worker thread. But both onResponse and onErrorResponse are called on the main thread so Toast.makeText is safe.